# TextMate: remove trailing spaces and save

Tags: textmate, code-folding

I'm using a script to remove trailing spaces and then save the file.

The problem is that all my code foldings expand when I use it. How do I change the command so it will keep the code foldings?

Comment: any feedback that would make the below answer "correct" to you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use foldingStartMarker & foldingStopMarker to indicate the folds to TextMate.

> To define a block that starts with { as the last non-space character on the line and stops with } as the first non-space character on the line, we can use the following patterns:

```
foldingStartMarker = '\{\s*$';

foldingStopMarker = '^\s*\}';
```

pressing the F1 key will fold any code folds present.

Reference: http://manual.macromates.com/en/navigation_overview#collapsing_text_blocks_foldings